# How to get data from MediaStore.File and MediaStore.File.FileColumn

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-file, mediastore

I am trying to get all the file name having audio files in it I have used Mediastore to get the mediastore **audio,album,playlist and audio DATA** also but how I can get the file or folder titles which contains the audio file .Here is the code that I have tried but it is not correct as I am not able to set the External_Content_uri.
This is the code I have tried.

```
  private void External() {
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.PARENT,
                MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA
        };// Can include more data for more details and check it.

        String selection =MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE+"=?";

        String[] selectionArgs = {"MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO"};

        String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

        Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("\"external\""), proj, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        if (audioCursor != null) {
            if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int filetitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE);
                    int file_id = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID);
                    int fileparent = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.PARENT);
                    int filedata = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);
                    Mediafileinfo info = new Mediafileinfo();
                    info.setData(new File(new File(audioCursor.getString(filedata)).getParent()).getName());
                    info.setTitle(audioCursor.getString(filetitle));
                    info.set_id(audioCursor.getString(file_id));
                    info.setParent(audioCursor.getString(fileparent));
                   // info.setData(audioCursor.getString(filedata));
                    audioList.add(info);
                } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        assert audioCursor != null;
        audioCursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.provider.MediaStore.Files.FileColumns) and [this](https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/ion-sample/src/com/koushikdutta/ion/sample/GallerySample.java) example but I am not able to get the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a fresh answer, since all you want is the folder names of the audio files.

So the best thing to use here is `MediaStore.Audio.Media` instead of using `MediaStore.File`. Get the folder names using the below on the audio file path.

```
new File(new File(audioCursor.getString(filedata)).getParent()).getName()
```

---

```
private void External() {
try {
    Uri externalUri= MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    projection=new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,;

    String selection =null;

    String[] selectionArgs = null;

    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC";

    Cursor audioCursor = getContentResolver().query(externalUri, proj, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

    if (audioCursor != null) {
        if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int filetitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int file_id = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int filePath = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                Mediafileinfo info = new Mediafileinfo();
                info.setData(new File(new File(audioCursor.getString(filedata)).getParent()).getName());
                info.setTitle(audioCursor.getString(filetitle));
                info.set_id(audioCursor.getString(file_id));
                audioList.add(info);
            } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    assert audioCursor != null;
    audioCursor.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Bro i am able to get every thing in MediaStore.Audio section but i want MediaStore.Files

Comment: you want file names of all music files, got that. Did you try the column value replacement with column name as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: I want to get the folder name that contains the media files

Comment: I tried ever possible way but I cant find any thing

Comment: names of folder which contain any type of media?

Comment: No thats why MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO so i can get the audio files

Comment: Ever used Media store.Files ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124151/discussion-between-neelay-srivastava-and-darshan-miskin).

Answer (score 2):

Hi query media file like audio,images and video using Android Media Store and Android Content Resolver, check this tutorial
http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/12/android-media-store-tutorial-list-all.html

**For Listing All images:**

```
private void parseAllImages() {
    try {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,
                null);


        int size = cursor.getCount();

        /*******  If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card. *****/

        if (size == 0) {

        } else {

            int thumbID = 0;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                int file_ColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                /**************** Captured image details ************/

                /*****  Used to show image on view in LoadImagesFromSDCard class ******/
                String path = cursor.getString(file_ColumnIndex);

                String fileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length());

                MediaFileInfo mediaFileInfo = new MediaFileInfo();
                mediaFileInfo.setFilePath(path);
                mediaFileInfo.setFileName(fileName);
                mediaFileInfo.setFileType(type);
                mediaList.add(mediaFileInfo);
            }
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

**For Listing all Video(.mp4)**

```
private void parseAllVideo() {
    try {
        String name = null;
        String[] thumbColumns = {MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID};

        int video_column_index;
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE};
        Cursor videocursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                proj, null, null, null);
        int count = videocursor.getCount();
        Log.d("No of video", "" + count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            MediaFileInfo mediaFileInfo = new MediaFileInfo();
            video_column_index = videocursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            videocursor.moveToPosition(i);
            name = videocursor.getString(video_column_index);

            mediaFileInfo.setFileName(name);

            int column_index = videocursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            videocursor.moveToPosition(i);
            String filepath = videocursor.getString(column_index);

            mediaFileInfo.setFilePath(filepath);
            mediaFileInfo.setFileType(type);
            mediaList.add(mediaFileInfo);
            // id += " Size(KB):" +
            // videocursor.getString(video_column_index);


        }
        videocursor.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

**For Listing All Audio**

```
private void parseAllAudio() {
    try {
        String TAG = "Audio";
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                null);

        if (cur == null) {
            // Query failed...
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to retrieve music: cursor is null :-(");

        }
        else if (!cur.moveToFirst()) {
            // Nothing to query. There is no music on the device. How boring.
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to move cursor to first row (no query results).");

        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Listing...");
            // retrieve the indices of the columns where the ID, title, etc. of the song are

            // add each song to mItems
            do {
                int artistColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                int titleColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int albumColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
                int durationColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
                int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int filePathIndex = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                Log.i(TAG, "Title column index: " + String.valueOf(titleColumn));
                Log.i(TAG, "ID column index: " + String.valueOf(titleColumn));

                Log.i("Final ", "ID: " + cur.getString(idColumn) + " Title: " + cur.getString(titleColumn) + "Path: " + cur.getString(filePathIndex));
                MediaFileInfo audio = new MediaFileInfo();
                audio.setFileName(cur.getString(titleColumn));
                audio.setFilePath(cur.getString(filePathIndex));
                audio.setFileType(type);
                mediaList.add(audio);

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: I am able to able to get all the data thx to your post i think app to get all types of data but here I want to Use Mediastore.file

Comment: I am able to get all the things you put in your answer I want to get the Files with media on it not the Audio.Data

Comment: can you tell me how I can use the Mediastore.Files or where i am doing wrong

Comment: can't we use MediaStore , this method for documents?